# Слитно или через дефис?

Tags: дефис

эстроген- и тестостерон-подобные вещества

Answer (score 2):

Здесь можно применить особую форму записи слова с союзом И и "висячим дефисом":эстрогено- и тестостероноподобные вещества.

Для сравнения: газо- и электросварка, англо, франко- и русскоязычные тексты, не двух-, а трёхэтажный дом.

Comment: Да, вы правы, София, так лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно писать: эстрогеноподобные и тестостероноподобные. Пример: древоподобные, жироподобные. Разделение гласной  согласных в данном случае обязательно. Дефис не нужен.